# Stopping a for loop for a python Pig Latin translator

Tags: python-3.6

I must create a program that turns a seprate file into Pig Latin.  My code does do this but the for loop I am using keeps going until Pig Latin gets rearranged wrong.

I was told to move my print statements out of the for loop but I am not sure what this means.

```
def part2():
  fin = open('Sonnet.txt')
  fin.readline()
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u']
  for line in fin:
    poem = line.split()
    print(poem)
    for word in range(len(poem)):
      for i in range(len(vowels)):  
        if vowels[i] in poem[word][0]:
          print(poem[word] + 'way')
        else: 
          print(poem[word][i:]+poem[word][0:i] + 'ay')
part2()
```

The seprate file is expected to be translated to Pig Latin. Rules for Pig Latin: If the word begins with a constant (including y), then all letters from the beginning of the word, up to the first vowel (excluding), are removed and then added to the end of the word, followed by ay. If the word begins with a vowel (not including y), then way is added to the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand; You are trying to stop a Loop in Python.

This can easily be accomplished by using `break`

For example:

```
while True:
     print('Hello World!')
else:
     break
```

If I am not understanding your question correctly, feel free to leave a comment on my answer and I will try to help more.

Thank You!

Comment: I tried break but it stopped the code to early to where the code did not finish what it was meant to do. The code that I have keeps running until the words on the file are rearranged in a way that is not Pig Latin.  My teacher told me to move to the print statements out of the for loop to stop it, but I am not sure what this means. I tried to do this but it did not work.

Comment: It sounds like what your teacher said, is exactly what you need to do. If you move your print statements out of the loop, you would be able to add another section stopping the loop once it's done, OR you could add something like; `process = 'done'` at the end of your code, then check to see if process = done...and if not, check again, if so. `break`

Comment: I am confused to which for loop I should move the print statements from.  Can you clarify please.

Comment: Absoloutely! So basically, what I was thinking, is for a solution without moving the print statements; you could add (once the process has finished) a variable that says when the process is done. Then check if the variable says it's done. As stated above, and if It is done, break, else; recheck.